# I'm using react bootstrap modal in my component but it does not open by onClick event call in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    I'm using react bootstrap modal in my component, but it does not open by onClick event call in another component. how to resolve this problem?

    this is my code

        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import classes from '../../Custom.css';
        import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
        //import ModalCart from '../../ModalCart';
        import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
        //import 'react-bootstrap';
        class Navi extends Component {`enter code here`
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              modal: false
            };
            this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
          }
          toggle() {
            this.setState({
              modal: !this.state.modal
            });
          }
            render() {
                return (
                    <header>
                  <div className="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary box-shadow">
                    <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <a href="" className="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
                        <strong><i className="fas fa-tags"></i> Products</strong>
                       </a>
                      <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle} className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                          <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                          <span className={classes.counter}>
                            Bag : {this.props.noItems} </span>
                            <span className={classes.counter}>
                           SUBTOTAL : <span>&#36;</span> {this.props.total.toFixed(2)}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        {this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </header>
                );
            }
        }
        export default Navi;




    this is second component where to call toggle button and my modal exit there-----

   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart';
import classes from '../src/Custom.css';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
//import Aux from '../src/Aux';


class ModalCart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modal: false
        };

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
      }

      toggle() {
        this.setState({
          modal: !this.state.modal
        });
      }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.cart);
        return (

            <div> 
              <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
              <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle} className={classes.modalheader}>Shopping Cart</ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody className="">
              <div className="modal-body">
                             <ShoppingCart
                                cart={this.props.cart}
                                onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                               checkOut={this.props.checkOut}
                               tot={this.props.total}
                               />
                      </div>
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
          </div>





        );
    }
}

export default ModalCart;


Both of the component are displayed here plz check and help it out why it does not working thanks .......it is a mind stuck procedure form help me out from this condition,
```

I'm using react bootstrap modal in my component but it does not open by onClick event call in another component...
can any body knows about it plz mention hem/ her their for help me out from this problem

all two components and their code i place here if i'm done any mistake highlight it resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not importing NavbarToggler.

```
import { NavbarToggler} from reactstrap;
```

in render() it will look like this

```
<NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
```